# Encrypt private key with passphrase using openssl ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl

In order to encrypt my private key and provide the passphrase. Currently, I am using bash cmd to get my encrypted key `user_enc.pem`

```
( openssl rsa -in user.pem -pubout && openssl rsa -in user.pem -aes256 ) > user_enc.pem
```

It would be helpful if someone can have a look and help me out to achieve this by using ruby probably with `openssl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL::Cipher, which belong to Ruby standard library, provides symmetric algorithms for encryption and decryption. To use it just require OpenSSL in Ruby:

```
require 'openssl'
```

You can create a cipher instance specifying the Cipher algorithm. For example:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
iv = cipher.random_iv

data = "Confidential data"
encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
```

For more details, check Ruby documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html